# Windows 7 fails to boot after hardware change

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

I got new hardware and wanted to keep my old Windows 7 installation. (I have done this before and it worked.) I moved the hard disk with the Windows on a SSD to the new PC and now I get a letter J followed by a blinking cursor. After searching all the old forums I have tried the following:

1. Switch the SATA mode in BIOS from IDE to AHCI, this leads to the good old  "reboot and select proper boot device" message.
2. Boot from my Windows 7 recovery USB, which has NO option to repair the installation and what is even more strange it is trying to install a fresh Windows 7 and shows the Disk with both partitions (Reserved System Partition and my Windows 7 Partition). Also I can scan for other drivers and browse my folder structure here (so everything is still there).

Any idea that do not lead to "reinstall Windows" is welcome :)

**Edit:** Just to be clear I have not found any way to get a console window or a command line where I can type.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a new motherboard?

Comment: Everything is new, besides the SSD.

Comment: There's your issue then, and I'm sure it's been asked here before. The SSD has your old PC's motherboard drivers on it, and they aren't compatible with the new motherboard. Hence, it won't boot. There are some ways around this. My method was to sysprep on the old system, and then transfer to the new PC so it is forced to find new drivers.

Comment: Like I said, that I did this before and I know all the typical issues that come along. What is new to me is that I cannot reach the repair option. Other PCs I have easily rescued with this http://www.wintips.org/how-to-replace-motherboard-without-re-installing-windows/ instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

As it turned out the MBR of the drive was defect. I mounted a second drive with a second Windows 7 on it. After booting the second OS, I used the tool from partitionwizard.com to fix the MBR. Now the first OS is back to live, I installed all missing/broken drivers and now everything work just fine.